# How to format currency in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables, currency-formatting

This is a table which display transactions, implementes using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).
[image]

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var table = $('#tbl_transaksi').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data_transaksi.php",
        "bPaginate":true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "columns": [
            { mData: 'username' } ,
            { mData: 'fullname' },
            { mData: 'the_date' },
            { mData: 'amount',  render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                return "Rp " + data;
                } 
            }
        ],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }); 

});
```

It works. Now I want to add an enhancement: format the amount ("jumlah") using Indonesian format, so for example **1000000** will be displayed as "**Rp 1.000.000**";

A Google search pointed me to [renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper). I added the render part into my code, and well it doesn't change the formatting. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 14):

use `$.fn.dataTable.render.number` function,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var table = $('#tbl_transaksi').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data_transaksi.php",
        "bPaginate":true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "columns": [
            { mData: 'username' } ,
            { mData: 'fullname' },
            { mData: 'the_date' },
            { mData: 'amount',  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 3, 'Rp' )
            }
        ],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Hmm tried this on both latest Chrome & Firefox... doesn't work. Yes I've reloaded the page several times...

Comment: Any syntex error you are getting or it renders in different format?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this thing solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#tbl_transaksi').DataTable({
    "ajax": "data_transaksi.php",
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "columns": [
      { mData: 'username' },
      { mData: 'fullname' },
      { mData: 'the_date' },
      {
        mData: 'amount', render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          return meta.settings.fnFormatNumber(row.amount);
        }
      }
    ],
    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use it gan :

```
{
  mData: 'amount',  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 0, 'Rp ' )
 }
//result Rp 175.000
```

in indonesian rupiah they use dot (.) for currency not comma